# Javascript regex test

Tags: javascript, regex

What test should I make to get all instances of substring of the pattern "$" + someSingleCharacter + "$"

in the following string for example:

"We need to eat $0$ melons per $1$ days"

Comment: Are you sure you need a regex? If you want to replace, a simple string patter will do.

Comment: What would will be the variable `someSingleCharacter` and the desired output matches for your example string? It looks like your question cannot be answered without knowing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should be:

```
/\$.\$/g
```

Here `.` is any character except new line. If you want to match new line character too, then use

```
/\$(?:.|\n)\$/g
```

Note that it will match `$$$` too. If you want to avoid it use

```
/\$[^\$]\$/g
```

However, although you didn't ask, I'm pretty sure you want something like this:

```
function replace(str, ...values){
  return str.replace(/\$\d+\$/g, () => values.shift());
}

var exampleStr = 'We need to eat $0$ melons per $1$ days.';
var replaced = replace(exampleStr, 'one', 'two');

console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: While all this will work as a regex, it's still not what the OP is after - he wants a regex where a simple string pattern will do, i.e. `replace("$"+0+"$", "123")`

Comment: @Filburt. I think you are wrong. If you look at his example, he has two different patterns (and maybe he hane n different patterns in some string), so he must use regex. Also, passing a string as a first argument to `String.prototype.replace` function will cause it to replace only the first occurence.

Comment: Of course, but why would he want to replace 2 different patterns with the same value? In any case a typical XY problem unless the OP gives the desired output for his example.

Comment: @Filburt. He never said he wants to replace the occurences. But anyway, I added what I think OP wants to my answer.

Comment: No need to escape the dollar sign inside the character set.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you want to use is `\$(.)\$`.

It looks for 1 single character (`.`) inside two `$` signs.

Comment: Wrong. As OP said, he wants to match only one character between dollar signs.

Comment: ... so rather `"\$(" + 0 + ")\$"` and/or `"\$(" + 1 + ")\$"`

Comment: ... but to me it looks as if regex isn't needed anyway for the OPs actual task.